# VBA Variable inside Filter CriteriaRange

Tags: vba, variables, filter, range, criteria

I am trying to set the filter criteria range as a variable but it's coming up as an error. I would like the filter to pick up the text inside a cell (U3) to use as the criteria range.

```
    Dim datefrom As String
    datefrom = Worksheets("Reference").Range("U3")
    Range("A3:EK10000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Worksheets("Reference").Range(datefrom), Unique:=False
```

Cell U3 contains the following string (hyphens included): "D3:D14"

Would appreciate some help on this as I'm really stuck.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to remove "" in U3. It will work.

Comment: No problem. If you want to maintain the "" in your U, simply use the replace function as follow: `dateform = replace(Worksheets("Reference").Range("U3"),""""","")`. It will remove the "" from U3.